# Created woocommerce product attribute programmatically and added terms to them but terms are not showing in Product->Attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created woo-commerce product attributes programmatically by the following code:

```
$data = array(
    'name'   => 'My attribute',
    'slug'    => wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name(wp_unslash('My attribute')),
    'type'    => 'select',
    'order_by' => 'menu_order',
    'has_archives'  => 1
  );        
 wc_create_attribute( $data );
```

and this code adds attributes successfully and are visible to the list of woo-commerce in Products->Attributes, but after that, I tried adding  some `terms` to them which are not affected to the attribute list by using following code:

```
wp_insert_term( 'term_1' ,'pa_'.$data['slug']);
```

also, I confirm that when I dump the result of `var_dump(get_term_by('name','term_1','pa_'.$data['slug']))` I get result with term id,name,slug,term_taxonomy_id etc., but the problem it these terms are not visible on the woocommerce product attributes and so does on product editing page.

Answer (score 7):

Because I've searched myself a lot before reaching out to a working solution that works for `Woocommerce 3.8+`, I give this answer in order others to get help on a really confusing topic such as Woocommerce Attributes.

I've created two methods/functions: `createAttribute` and `createTerm` based on the sample code that `Woocomerce` provides as an example: [See code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/20d7603dd6ea87049842560de3f98fa4840706d1/tests/framework/helpers/class-wc-helper-product.php#L158-L246)

```php
function createAttribute(string $attributeName, string $attributeSlug): ?\stdClass {
    delete_transient('wc_attribute_taxonomies');
    \WC_Cache_Helper::incr_cache_prefix('woocommerce-attributes');

    $attributeLabels = wp_list_pluck(wc_get_attribute_taxonomies(), 'attribute_label', 'attribute_name');
    $attributeWCName = array_search($attributeSlug, $attributeLabels, TRUE);

    if (! $attributeWCName) {
        $attributeWCName = wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name($attributeSlug);
    }

    $attributeId = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($attributeWCName);
    if (! $attributeId) {
        $taxonomyName = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attributeWCName);
        unregister_taxonomy($taxonomyName);
        $attributeId = wc_create_attribute(array(
            'name' => $attributeName,
            'slug' => $attributeSlug,
            'type' => 'select',
            'order_by' => 'menu_order',
            'has_archives' => 0,
        ));

        register_taxonomy($taxonomyName, apply_filters('woocommerce_taxonomy_objects_' . $taxonomyName, array(
            'product'
        )), apply_filters('woocommerce_taxonomy_args_' . $taxonomyName, array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => $attributeSlug,
            ),
            'hierarchical' => FALSE,
            'show_ui' => FALSE,
            'query_var' => TRUE,
            'rewrite' => FALSE,
        )));
    }

    return wc_get_attribute($attributeId);
}
```

```php
function createTerm(string $termName, string $termSlug, string $taxonomy, int $order = 0): ?\WP_Term {
    $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($taxonomy);

    if (! $term = get_term_by('slug', $termSlug, $taxonomy)) {
        $term = wp_insert_term($termName, $taxonomy, array(
            'slug' => $termSlug,
        ));
        $term = get_term_by('id', $term['term_id'], $taxonomy);
        if ($term) {
            update_term_meta($term->term_id, 'order', $order);
        }
    }

    return $term;
}
```

So they can be used like:

```php
createAttribute('Colors', 'my-colors');
createTerm('Red', 'my-red', 'my-colors', 10);
createTerm('Green', 'my-green', 'my-colors', 20);
createTerm('Blue', 'my-blue', 'my-colors', 30);
```

Comment: Great job specially on `register_taxonomy`